# Текст до ссылки автоматически становится синий

Tags: html, текст

Весь текст, который стоит до тега `<а href>` внутри тега `<p>` автоматически становится такого же цвета как ссылка (синий). Как сделать так, чтобы цвет текста оставался исходным?

```html
<p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  <a href="">cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur </a>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: проверьте закрыты ли теги

Comment: Задайте тегу `<p>` свои стили.

Answer (score 1):

Все должно работать, проверьте ещо раз.
Так же проверьте может где-то другой стиль перебивает ваш.

В `CSS` есть значение написание стилей и их размещение в файле - читаются стили с горы в низ.

```css
a{
color:blue;
text-decoration:none;
}
a{
color:red;
}
p{
color:green !important; 
}
```

```html
<p> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
<a href="">cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur </a>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Немного поправил (добавил `р`). Возможно на тег `р` у вас прописаны ещо стили. Напишите свои стили которые у вас написаны, так как у вас проблема из `CSS` а вы подаете только `html`